# Find overlapping seasons where seasons have_many date_ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I have the following setup:

```
class Season < AR::Base
  has_many :date_ranges
end

class DateRange < AR::Base
  # has a :starts_at & :ends_at
end
```

How would I find all overlapping seasons from a season instance? I have already tried with a couple of different queries (below). But the problem I keep hitting is the fact that the season im checking for also possible has multiple date_ranges. I could solve it with a loop but i'd rather only use a query.

This query looks up all the seasons that overlap but it only does that for 1 input date_range
`Season.joins(:date_ranges).where("starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?", ends_at, starts_at`)

Maybe I need something to chain a couple of OR's together for each date_range on the instance but `where()` only uses AND.

So in short, finding the overlap is not the problem, but how do I find overlap of multiple date_ranges to the entire database?

Comment: MySQL but if possible i'd like to have it compatible with others as well

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is through straight SQL. Something like this:

```
DateRange.find_by_sql(%q{
    select a.*
    from date_ranges a
    join date_ranges b on
            a.id < b.id
        and (
               (a.ends_at   >= b.starts_at and a.ends_at   <= b.ends_at)
            or (a.starts_at >= b.starts_at and a.starts_at <= b.ends_at)
            or (a.starts_at <= b.starts_at and a.ends_at   >= b.ends_at)
        )
    where season_id = ?
}, season_id)
```

The basic idea is to join the table to itself so that you can easily compare the ranges. The `a.id < b.id` is there to get unique results and filter out "ranges matches itself" cases. The inner `or` conditions check for both types of overlaps:

```
[as-----ae]            [as-----ae]    
    [bs-----be]    [bs-----be]
```

and

```
[as--------------ae]         [as----ae]
     [bs----be]         [bs--------------be]
```

You might want to think about the end points though, that query considers two intervals to overlap if they only match at an endpoint and that might not be what you want.

Presumably you already have a unique constraint on the `(season_id, starts_at, ends_at)` triples and presumably you're already ensuring that `starts_at <= ends_at`.